# Start SharePoint workflow on certain time of day or after a certain amount of time

Tags: sharepoint, moss, workflow, infopath

Is it possible to start a workflow on a document in SharePoint 2007 that begins after a certain time or on a certain date?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2009/01/25/starting-a-sharepoint-workflow-from-code-event-receiver.aspx) is an example of how you can start a workflow programmatically, it kicks the workflow off from an EventReceiver.

And [here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/CreatingCustomSharePointTimerJobs.aspx) is an example of how to create a SharePoint timer job (these can be run at a certain time of day or after a period of time).

With a bit of work these two concepts should get you what you want. In your case instead of kicking the workflow off from an event receiver you will be kicking it off from the timer jobs Execute call.